# FOL question on formalization of natural language mathematics

Tags: first-order-logic

Would the following be a correct formalization of this natural language sentence?: "Every real number has an inverse"

$∀x∃y(x+y=0 \land ∀z(z+x=0→ z=y))$

I thought that the first part of the conjunction would not be sufficient to express the meaning of the sentence, since it does not necessarily entail that there exists a unique inverse. The second part of the conjunction (the one with the universal quantifier should do the work, I guess, but I am not sure I am right.
Also, in this case, I implicitly assumed to fix my referenc to a domain that is equivalent to real numbers, otherwise I think I would have had to specify:

$∀x∃y(R(x) \land R(y) \rightarrow (x+y=0 \land ∀z(R(z) \rightarrow (z+x=0→ z=y))))$

Comment: Correct, but the specification of "uniqueness" is needed if you start with "Every real number has a **unique** inverse"

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: In pure classic FOL with strictly only 2 basic types of quantifiers, your second part is required. This is called Russell's definite description theory in philosophy of language regarding the subtle matters of sense and reference, see reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the precise meaning of the word "inverse" in the sentence "every real number has an inverse". If by "inverse" you mean "unique additive inverse", then the following is correct:
$$
\forall x:\exists y:x+y=0 \land \forall z:x+z=0 \implies z =y \, .
$$
We often write $\exists!y :P(y)$ (read: there exists a unique $y$ such that $P(y)$ is true) as an abbreviation of
$$
\exists y : P(y) \land \forall z:P(z) \implies z=y \, .
$$
So we could also write
$$
\forall x:\exists!y:x+y=0 \, .
$$
If the additive inverse is not required to be unique, then we could simply write
$$
\forall x: \exists y: x+y=0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks: shouldn't we write in in the first formula: ∀z:x+z=0⟹x=y? This due to the fact that this generalization is true only for x=0, I think

Comment: @PwNzDust: See my updated answer. It should actually be $$\forall x:\exists y:x+y=0 \land \forall z:x+z=0 \implies z =y \, .$$